# Facebook Like button Integration in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to integrate the Facebook Like button in my android application.

Please tell me Steps how to integrate it in Android.

Comment: I just posted my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794677/facebook-like-button-in-android-application/14793732#14793732
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do it with a webview that contains the standard html integration that you get from [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). Just define the widht and height of the webview the same as used in the xml and see if the outcome is good enough and works for your application.

Comment: Once pressed, how would the interaction look like?

Comment: Good question the webview would have to make it possible for the user to login

Comment: Thanks for reply
I have created a webview.how to integrate HTML in that pls tell the code.