# Integrating the Like Button of Facebook in an android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I am working on an application where I need to integrate the Like functionality of Facebook, other than Like I have completed all the features including Share, Upload, etc..

I am stuck in Like because I did,'t find anything for Like in the Facebook SDK I found from the Net on demand.

Can anybody please help me in this, any help or link will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
david

Comment: David Brown Have u done uploading local video file ?? if so plz post me any link that explains abt uploading local video to fb .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are correct in that there is no Like functionality in the SDK.

It seems that the best way is to use a WebView with the standard Javascript code available from [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), however I think this way has it's own problems but looks like it can be accomplished...

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108088/android-webview-for-facebook-like-button) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449758/facebook-like-button-integration-in-android).

Answer (score -2):

If you have OBJECT_ID for the item you want to like, it shouldn't require anything else than sending an empty HTTP POST to http://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes .

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
mFacebook.request(objectId + "/likes", params, "POST");
```

See [Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) in developer docs.