# Linking a Facebook Page to android

Tags: android, facebook

Does anyone know to link a page created in **Facebook** (Company/Fan page ) with a **like** button in android.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at following questions and answer, see if its same what you are looking for.

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794677/facebook-like-button-in-android-application)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475986/android-facebook-like-button)